# Intellij azure-webapp plugin: Encoutering error when deploying to azure: 'No available subscription found in current account.'

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, spring-boot-maven-plugin, azure-webapps

I have a valid Azure free trial subscription and I want to deploy a local spring boot app to azure.

I have configured the azure-webapp-maven-plugin in my pom.xml. I am using Intellij.

When i execute **mvn azure-webapp:deploy**, i get the following error:

`Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:deploy (default-cli) on project movie-catalog-service: Encoutering error when deploying to azure: 'No available subscription found in current account.`'

[image]

Edit 1: I installed azure CLI and from my command line it is able to find the subsciption. I followed this url:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos?view=azure-cli-latest

[image: Hidden some personal info]

But still cannot find the same from Intellij.

I tried azure-webapp deploy with Azure CLI. Still same

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. And the issue is now opened [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-dev-docs/issues/127).

If Azure CLI is installed and sub is detected correctly. 
You can try to use Azure CLI Auth insstead of Maven plug-in. 
You can do that by adding config in your azure-webapp-maven-plugin configuration in pom.

```
<authType>azure_cli</authType>
```

It would be like this:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
    <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>1.9.1</version>  
    <configuration>
      <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
      <authType>azure_cli</authType>
      <resourceGroup>someg-group</resourceGroup>
      <appName>some-app-name</appName>
      <pricingTier>P1v2</pricingTier>
      <region>westeurope</region>
      ....
</plugin>
```